# How do I get the type of a list property when using conditional types?

Tags: typescript, types

Given the following types:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
};

type Family = {
  parent: Person;
  children: Person[];
};
```

I want to define another type `Aggregated<T>` which would auto generate the following type:

```
type FamilyAggregatedExpected = {
  parent: Person[];
  children: Aggregated<Person>[];
};
```

that is:

- for a non-list property, the new type contains an array of values with the same type as the original property
- for a list property, the new type contains an array of values with type of `Aggregated<T>`

I am having difficulty with the list properties.

So far I have tried:

```
export type Aggregated<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends any[] ? Aggregated<any>[] : T[key][];
};
```

but this does not type the `Aggregated` type parameter. Trying to resolve this:

```
export type Aggregated<T,U = never> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends U[] ? Aggregated<U>[] : T[key][];
};
```

which does not work as `extends U[]` always fails.

How can I extract the list element type so I can pass it to `Aggregated<T>`?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-conditional-types?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this; the one that seems closest to your approach is to get [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) using an `infer` declaration:

```
type Aggregated<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<infer U> ? Aggregated<U>[] : T[K][];
};
```

For each property key `K` in the keys of `T`, we check to see if `T[K]` is an array of type `Array<infer U>`.  If so, `U` will be the element type of the array, and we can pass it to `Aggregated` as desired.  Let's make sure it works:

```
type FamilyAggregated = Aggregated<Family>
/* type FamilyAggregated = {
    parent: Person[];
    children: Aggregated<Person>[];
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAblwF8XdRIoAxU2gDYhMOfFDBF4EVMEpwkaFgQDGAC0EATKajkIUqANoBdFu1ydw0AIIMGUhkWAQNAHgAqAPhF4CBgNJQ9FAA1hAgyABmUG5GlG7+RlAQAB5OqBqIUFbw8EQgLvQRCFAAql4A-Fm29o7OLmXGUHEJxqYcXNB8JIIgNnYQDk4aAKLJkMpD3mIS2rKwemitYmqa2pR9NUMu8voeS2YW3F09GwO1GiKng3XHQh64APQAVFAdvPxCV+dTBAQz0nMdosTGIVOoBFppOtqmctkDUHsQawoE8HuYAG6SKDIYKUW69GHXEZjCATZwsTHwbG497dT6E85MKAPB6EZBJHLIKkAI1JRAArohoMBVGEAORSV6iqikCBAA)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the quick answer. I was trying to to something along these lines but wasn't familiar with `infer` so was trying to use an additional type parameter.